# CSS Centering Issue for Navigation Menu

Tags: css, menu, navigation, center

I need some help with some CSS coding. I have been trying to get this navigation menu to center on the page and no matter what I do, I cannot get it to work. I have tried padding-left, margin-left, text-align:center, and nothing works. The menu continues to remain more to the left than the right.

Here is a screenshot of the problem: http://i132.photobucket.com/albums/q38/blacktiphunter/center.jpg

I'm sure it's something very simple, but I just can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong?

**Here is the live link of the page:** http://blacktiphfishing.org/test.html

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you post your css please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first add `overflow:hidden` for `#nav, #nav ul` to clear floats. Then add `margin:0 auto` .But this always require a fixed width, so set it, for example: `width:760px` So the new css is:

```
#nav, #nav ul {
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 760px;
    z-index: 30;
}
```

Comment: @VAShhh I wrote for `#nav` so in this case is (150px+2px)*5 = 760px

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried your code and I found that the overflow:hidden caused the sub-menu to not display?

Comment: @Joshua Jorgensen if you don't clear the floats, then the design "breaks" and create the issue you had

Answer (score 2):

If you remove the

`margin:0;` from `#nav`

it looks centered.

*Tested in Chrome*

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the exact width of the `MainMenu` div and set his left-right margin to auto if you want to reach a correct centered layout.

The exact width would be **780px** (**150px * 5** (5 link each row) + **10px * 2** (10px left + 10px right border) + **2px * 5** (right margin of each li))

Use this css :

```
#mainMenu {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;
    border: 10px solid #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 780px;
}
```

To get the nav section centered

Comment: Thank you for your help. I used your code as it and the navigation menu didn't center completely. The menu was more towards the left, than the right. 

I changed:

width:780px; to width:760px;

and the navigation menu was centered perfectly. 

May I ask why you added more code to the background?

Comment: I didn't added any code, the code you see was provided by firebug - infact the `background` instruction is pretty useless, the things I've added are the `fixed width` and the `left-right margin auto`;) glad it worked, don't forget to approve the solution for your question!

Comment: How do I approve the solution? I am new to this site and I am not familiar with the format.

Answer (score 0):

CSS layouts can be a bit of a headache sometimes. Try using 'inspect element' in chrome or [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) in firefox to enable/disable and alter styles to get fine tuned adjustments